# Despite creating a session, when a person navigates to a second page, it acts as though the session never existed

Tags: php, sql, session

For some reason despite the fact that IsLoggedIn() is checking for the session, it acts as though none exists.

I used this to create the functions

```
<?php
session_start();
function DoLogin($email, $password)
{
    $sql = "
            SELECT U.id, password, FirstName, LastName
            FROM Users U
                    Join ContactMethods CM On U.id=CM.User_Id
            WHERE CM.`Value` = '$email'
            ";
    $conn = getConnection();
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    //echo $conn->error;
    $rs = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $conn->close();
    if($rs['password'] == $password)
    {
            $_SESSION['UserId'] = $rs['id'];
            $_SESSION['UserEmail'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['UserName'] = $rs['FirstName'] . ' ' . $rs['LastName'];
    }
}
function IsLoggedIn()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['UserId']);
}
```

and this on top of pages

```
require_once('inc/loginauth.php'); // calls the script with the functions listed above
   if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
            DoLogin($_REQUEST['email'],$_REQUEST['password']);
?>
```

and this for the login piece on each page

```
 <?php
         session_start();
if(IsLoggedIn()){ ?>
            <h2>Welome <?=GetUserName()?>!</h2>     
            <p class="grey">Would You Like to Log Out?</p>
            <p class="grey"><a href="<?=DoLogOut()?>">Log Out</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <!-- Login Form --><? }else{ ?>
    <form method="post">
                        <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
            <input class="field" type="email" name="email" />
            <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
        <input class="field" type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" class="bt_login" value="Log In" />
    </form>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: session_start(); needs to be on the pages you use the session

Comment: I suggest that you look in to some examples on how to create secure login scripts with PHP. This solution has no protection against session hijacking for instance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put `session_start();` at the beginning of the second script (if the session is not started automatically)
2. Try `var_dump($_SESSION);` in the second script to see what you have in the session.
3. Don't use short open PHP tags `<? ?>`. They are deprecated. Use full tags `<?php ?>`

Comment: when i do var_dump($_Session); it shows nothing in the arrays. I replaced everything with <?php and put session_start() however still having problems. It's as if the session isn't being kept?

Comment: Try simple script examples from PHP `session_start()` manual to make sure the session works on your server. If it works, check that the session variables are set in the first script. If they are - start splitting your code into smaller pieces and track down what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the session start within the php function.

also the start and end delimiters are `<?php if(IsLoggedIn()){ ?>`

Comment: i did as recommended still have issues ill edit my post with the changes